# Need to generate node info files per build, even-though node.conf remains the same

Tags: corda

I am running our corda application in a docker environment. Due to this I generate node info files for each node and copy them to the nodes to bring up the application. Initially I assumed I could use the same node info file as long as the node.conf remained the same, however this is not the case.

- If I use the same node info files after a rebuild. The nodes come up fine connecting with each other. However when a flow is initiated, I get the following AMQP error from one of the nodes (security.ActiveMQJAASSecurityManager.validateUser - Couldn't validate user {}), complete stack trace is below.
- If I copy the node info file and the contents of the certificates directories used when the node info file was generated I get contract validation error.

Note that each time I am starting up the corda network from scratch.

- Is this behavior expected?
- If the node.conf remains the same then to what attributes are the node info files tied into of a given build (root certificate etc)?
- Is the root dev certificate changed each time it builds?

I am trying to understand how this is setup in order to setup our test environment.

Thanks

Complete Stack Trace:

```
auditorcontainer | D 18:25:36+0000 [Thread-4 (activemq-netty-threads)] security.ActiveMQJAASSecurityManager.validateUser - Couldn't validate user {}
auditorcontainer |  javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: Username not provided
auditorcontainer |      at net.corda.node.services.messaging.NodeLoginModule.login(ArtemisMessagingServer.kt:255) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
auditorcontainer |      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
auditorcontainer |      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
auditorcontainer |      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
auditorcontainer |      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
auditorcontainer |      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:755) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
auditorcontainer |      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
auditorcontainer |      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
auditorcontainer |      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
auditorcontainer |      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
auditorcontainer |      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
auditorcontainer |      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.ActiveMQJAASSecurityManager.getAuthenticatedSubject(ActiveMQJAASSecurityManager.java:186) ~[artemis-server-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.ActiveMQJAASSecurityManager.validateUser(ActiveMQJAASSecurityManager.java:93) [artemis-server-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.security.impl.SecurityStoreImpl.authenticate(SecurityStoreImpl.java:129) [artemis-server-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.amqp.broker.AMQPConnectionCallback.isSupportsAnonymous(AMQPConnectionCallback.java:105) [artemis-amqp-protocol-2.2.0.jar:?]
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.amqp.broker.AMQPConnectionCallback.getSASLMechnisms(AMQPConnectionCallback.java:93) [artemis-amqp-protocol-2.2.0.jar:?]
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.amqp.proton.AMQPConnectionContext.onAuthInit(AMQPConnectionContext.java:324) [artemis-amqp-protocol-2.2.0.jar:?]
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.amqp.proton.handler.ProtonHandler.dispatchAuth(ProtonHandler.java:326) [artemis-amqp-protocol-2.2.0.jar:?]
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.amqp.proton.handler.ProtonHandler.inputBuffer(ProtonHandler.java:221) [artemis-amqp-protocol-2.2.0.jar:?]
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocofl.amqp.proton.AMQPConnectionContext.inputBuffer(AMQPConnectionContext.java:125) [artemis-amqp-protocol-2.2.0.jar:?]
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.amqp.broker.ActiveMQProtonRemotingConnection.bufferReceived(ActiveMQProtonRemotingConnection.java:138) [artemis-amqp-protocol-2.2.0.jar:?]
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.server.impl.RemotingServiceImpl$DelegatingBufferHandler.bufferReceived(RemotingServiceImpl.java:631) [artemis-server-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.ActiveMQChannelHandler.channelRead(ActiveMQChannelHandler.java:68) [artemis-core-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.handlerRemoved(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:219) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerRemoved0(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:631) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.remove(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:468) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.remove(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:428) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.ProtocolHandler$ProtocolDecoder.decode(ProtocolHandler.java:186) [artemis-server-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.ProtocolHandler$ProtocolDecoder.channelRead(ProtocolHandler.java:128) [artemis-server-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1240) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1041) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-all-4.1.9.Fin:qll.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:1017) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:394) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:299) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_151]
auditorcontainer | D 18:25:36+0000 [Thread-4 (activemq-netty-threads)] impl.PostOfficeImpl.route - Couldn't find any bindings for address=internal.activemq.notifications on message=CoreMessage[messageID=32,durable=true,userID=null,priority=0, timestamp=0,expiration=0, durable=true, address=internal.activemq.notifications,properties=TypedProperties[_AMQ_NotifType=SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION_VIOLATION,_AMQ_NotifTimestamp=1534530336155]]@339279392 {}
auditorcontainer | D 18:25:36+0000 [Thread-4 (activemq-netty-threads)] impl.PostOfficeImpl.route - Message CoreMessage[messageID=32,durable=true,userID=null,priority=0, timestamp=0,expiration=0, durable=true, address=internal.activemq.notifications,properties=TypedProperties[_AMQ_NotifType=SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION_VIOLATION,_AMQ_NotifTimestamp=1534530336155]]@339279392 is not going anywhere as it didn't have a binding on address:internal.activemq.notifications {}
auditorcontainer | D 18:25:36+0000 [Thread-4 (activemq-netty-threads)] messaging.NodeLoginModule.login - Processing login for SystemUsers/Peer {}
auditorcontainer | D 18:25:36+0000 [Thread-4 (activemq-netty-threads)] security.ActiveMQJAASSecurityManager.validateUser - Couldn't validate user {}
auditorcontainer |  javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No TLS?
auditorcontainer |      at net.corda.node.services.messaging.NodeLoginModule$determineUserRole$1.invoke(ArtemisMessagingServer.kt:296)
auditorcontainer |      at net.corda.node.services.messaging.NodeLoginModule.determineUserRole(ArtemisMessagingServer.kt:299)
auditorcontainer |      at net.corda.node.services.messaging.NodeLoginModule.login(ArtemisMessagingServer.kt:261)
auditorcontainer |      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
auditorcontainer |      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
auditorcontainer |      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
auditorcontainer |      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
auditorcontainer |      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:755)
auditorcontainer |      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195)
auditorcontainer |      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682)
auditorcontainer |      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680)
auditorcontainer |      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
auditorcontainer |      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
auditorcontainer |      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.ActiveMQJAASSecurityManager.getAuthenticatedSubject(ActiveMQJAASSecurityManager.java:186)
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.ActiveMQJAASSecurityManager.validateUser(ActiveMQJAASSecurityManager.java:93)
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.security.impl.SecurityStoreImpl.authenticate(SecurityStoreImpl.java:129)
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.amqp.sasl.PlainSASL.authenticate(PlainSASL.java:33)
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.amqp.sasl.ServerSASLPlain.processSASL(ServerSASLPlain.java:48)
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.amqp.proton.handler.ProtonHandler.checkServerSASL(ProtonHandler.java:306)
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.amqp.proton.handler.ProtonHandler.flush(ProtonHandler.java:271)
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.amqp.proton.handler.ProtonHandler.inputBuffer(ProtonHandler.java:240)
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.amqp.proton.AMQPConnectionContext.inputBuffer(AMQPConnectionContext.java:125)
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.amqp.broker.ActiveMQProtonRemotingConnection.bufferReceived(ActiveMQProtonRemotingConnection.java:138)
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.server.impl.RemotingServiceImpl$DelegatingBufferHandler.bufferReceived(RemotingServiceImpl.java:631)
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.ActiveMQChannelHandler.channelRead(ActiveMQChannelHandler.java:68)
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.handlerRemoved(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:219)
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerRemoved0(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:631)
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.remove(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:468)
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.remove(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:428)
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.ProtocolHandler$ProtocolDecoder.decode(ProtocolHandler.java:186)
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411)
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248)
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.ProtocolHandler$ProtocolDecoder.channelRead(ProtocolHandler.java:128)
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1240)
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1041)
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411)
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248)
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926)
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:1017)
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:394)
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:299)
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
auditorcontainer |      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
auditorcontainer |
auditorcontainer |      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:856) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
auditorcontainer |      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
auditorcontainer |      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
auditorcontainer |      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
auditorcontainer |      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
auditorcontainer |      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
auditorcontainer |      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.ActiveMQJAASSecurityManager.getAuthenticatedSubject(ActiveMQJAASSecurityManager.java:186) ~[artemis-server-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.ActiveMQJAASSecurityManager.validateUser(ActiveMQJAASSecurityManager.java:93) [artemis-server-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.security.impl.SecurityStoreImpl.authenticate(SecurityStoreImpl.java:129) [artemis-server-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.amqp.sasl.PlainSASL.authenticate(PlainSASL.java:33) [artemis-amqp-protocol-2.2.0.jar:?]
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.amqp.sasl.ServerSASLPlain.processSASL(ServerSASLPlain.java:48) [artemis-amqp-protocol-2.2.0.jar:?]
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.amqp.proton.handler.ProtonHandler.checkServerSASL(ProtonHandler.java:306) [artemis-amqp-protocol-2.2.0.jar:?]
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.amqp.proton.handler.ProtonHandler.flush(ProtonHandler.java:271) [artemis-amqp-protocol-2.2.0.jar:?]
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.amqp.proton.handler.ProtonHandler.inputBuffer(ProtonHandler.java:240) [artemis-amqp-protocol-2.2.0.jar:?]
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.amqp.proton.AMQPConnectionContext.inputBuffer(AMQPConnectionContext.java:125) [artemis-amqp-protocol-2.2.0.jar:?]
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.amqp.broker.ActiveMQProtonRemotingConnection.bufferReceived(ActiveMQProtonRemotingConnection.java:138) [artemis-amqp-protocol-2.2.0.jar:?]
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.server.impl.RemotingServiceImpl$DelegatingBufferHandler.bufferReceived(RemotingServiceImpl.java:631) [artemis-server-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.ActiveMQChannelHandler.channelRead(ActiveMQChannelHandler.java:68) [artemis-core-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.handlerRemoved(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:219) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerRemoved0(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:631) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.remove(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:468) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.remove(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:428) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.ProtocolHandler$ProtocolDecoder.decode(ProtocolHandler.java:186) [artemis-server-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.ProtocolHandler$ProtocolDecoder.channelRead(ProtocolHandler.java:128) [artemis-server-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1240) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1041) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:1017) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:394) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:299) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
auditorcontainer |      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_151]
```

Comment: add more context to your question, otherwise you probably will not receive good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking each case individually:

- If I use the same node info files after a rebuild. The nodes come up fine connecting with each other. However when a flow is initiated, I get the following AMQP error from one of the nodes (security.ActiveMQJAASSecurityManager.validateUser - Couldn't validate user {}), complete stack trace is below.

The issue in this case is that when a node first starts up, it generates a new public/private keypair. It then uses this keypair to generate its certificates and `nodeInfo`. The keypair in the `nodeInfo` and the certificates must match. This is why you're seeing user validation errors when replacing the `nodeInfo` but not the certificates.

- If I copy the node info file and the contents of the certificates directories used when the node info file was generated I get contract validation error.

The issue in this case is that as of Corda 3, each network has a whitelist of accepted contract JAR files. I assume that as part of rebuilding the node, you're rebuilding the CorDapp JAR files. Because the JAR files contain timestamps, their hashes will not be identical across builds, and the network will not recognise the new CorDapp JAR, causing contract verification to fail. However, if you're using the bootstrapper, you can update the contract whitelist using the instructions [here](https://docs.corda.net/network-bootstrapper.html#updating-the-contract-whitelist-for-bootstrapped-networks).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [corda certificates docs](https://docs.corda.net/permissioning.html), the nodes require certificates because they use them to connect to each other (it is a permissioned network after all). As a result you cannot use the same certificates and therefore each node must have its own certificates.

If you want to automate your build process, I recommend using the [network bootstrapper tool](https://docs.corda.net/network-bootstrapper.html#bootstrapping-a-test-network) to bootstrap your network. You can use the same config file (i.e. the same settings as you are using docker), you just have to have several copies of it: e.g. node1.conf, node2.conf etc. Once you have all the files in a repository, you can simply run

```
java -jar network-bootstrapper-VERSION.jar --dir <nodes-root-dir>
```

and it will generate the required /nodes folders for you to run your network from. If you do it this way, you do not necessarily have to rebuild the network each time, although you can.

You can download the tool from [here](https://corda.net/resources).

Comment: Unfortunately the bootstrapper has the same issue as corda for generating node info files, where it performs a network name lookup of the nodes names.I outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51750001/corda-generating-node-info-manually-just-generate-node-info-forces-host-look    .  For node names which are accessible in the network it would be definitely a good recemendation.